# QGraphicsItem position not updated (PyQt4)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qgraphicsitem

I'm trying to guess how to update the position of the edge when the nodes are moved or why it's not been automatically updated. I have found that the position of the nodes is not updated if I remove the self.update() from the mouseReleaseEvent but I don't know which is the mecanism to get the same on the edge class. Can anybody help me with this?
EDIT: With "position"  I mean the value got by getPos()  or getScenePos() for the QEdgeGraphicItem. It's printed on the output for the nodes and the Edge.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import math

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QGraphicsView, QGraphicsTextItem


class QEdgeGraphicItem(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):
    Type = QtGui.QGraphicsItem.UserType + 2

    def __init__(self, sourceNode, destNode, label=None):
        super(QEdgeGraphicItem, self).__init__()

        self.sourcePoint = QtCore.QPointF()
        self.destPoint = QtCore.QPointF()

        self.setAcceptedMouseButtons(QtCore.Qt.NoButton)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)
        # self.setCacheMode(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.DeviceCoordinateCache)
        self.source = sourceNode
        self.dest = destNode

        self.label = QGraphicsTextItem("WHY IN THE HELL IS IT IN 0,0", self)
        self.label.setParentItem(self)
        self.label.setDefaultTextColor(QtCore.Qt.black)
        self.source.addEdge(self)
        self.dest.addEdge(self)
        self.adjust()

    def adjust(self):
        if not self.source or not self.dest:
            return

        line = QtCore.QLineF(self.mapFromItem(self.source, 0, 0),
                             self.mapFromItem(self.dest, 0, 0))
        self.prepareGeometryChange()
        self.sourcePoint = line.p1()
        self.destPoint = line.p2()

    def boundingRect(self):
        if not self.source or not self.dest:
            return QtCore.QRectF()
        extra = 2
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.sourcePoint,
                             QtCore.QSizeF(self.destPoint.x() - self.sourcePoint.x(),
                                           self.destPoint.y() - self.sourcePoint.y())).normalized().adjusted(-extra,
                                                                                                             -extra,
                                                                                                             extra,
                                                                                                             extra)
    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        if not self.source or not self.dest:
            return

        # Draw the line itself.
        line = QtCore.QLineF(self.sourcePoint, self.destPoint)

        if line.length() == 0.0:
            return

        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 1, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine,
                                  QtCore.Qt.RoundCap, QtCore.Qt.RoundJoin))
        painter.drawLine(line)

        painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush)
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.red)
        painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())
        print "Edge:"+str(self.scenePos().x()) + " " + str(self.scenePos().y())


class QNodeGraphicItem(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):
    Type = QtGui.QGraphicsItem.UserType + 1

    def __init__(self, label):
        super(QNodeGraphicItem, self).__init__()

        # self.graph = graphWidget
        self.edgeList = []
        self.newPos = QtCore.QPointF()

        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)
        # self.setCacheMode(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.DeviceCoordinateCache)
        # self.setZValue(1)
        self.size = 40
        self.border_width = 4

    def type(self):
        return QNodeGraphicItem.Type

    def addEdge(self, edge):
        self.edgeList.append(edge)
        edge.adjust()

    def boundingRect(self):
        x_coord = y_coord = (-1*(self.size/2)) - self.border_width
        width = height = self.size+23+self.border_width
        return QtCore.QRectF(x_coord, y_coord , width,
                             height)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        x_coord = y_coord = -(self.size / 2)
        width = height = self.size
        painter.save()

        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(100, 0, 200, 127)))
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
        painter.drawEllipse(x_coord, y_coord, width, height)

        painter.restore()
        print "Node: " + str(self.scenePos().x()) + " " + str(self.scenePos().y())

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionHasChanged:
            for edge in self.edgeList:
                edge.adjust()
        return super(QNodeGraphicItem, self).itemChange(change, value)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.update()
        super(QNodeGraphicItem, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.update()
        super(QNodeGraphicItem, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtCore.qsrand(QtCore.QTime(0, 0, 0).secsTo(QtCore.QTime.currentTime()))
    node1 = QNodeGraphicItem("Node1")
    node2 = QNodeGraphicItem("Node2")
    edge  = QEdgeGraphicItem(node1,node2)
    view = QGraphicsView()
    view.setCacheMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.CacheBackground)
    view.setViewportUpdateMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.BoundingRectViewportUpdate)
    view.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
    view.setTransformationAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
    view.setResizeAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorViewCenter)

    view.scale(0.8, 0.8)
    view.setMinimumSize(400, 400)
    view.setWindowTitle("Example")
    scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(view)
    scene.setItemIndexMethod(QtGui.QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)
    scene.setSceneRect(-400, -400, 800, 800)
    view.setScene(scene)
    scene.addItem(node1)
    scene.addItem(node2)
    scene.addItem(edge)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it is not updated, I see that if you move the QEdgeGraphicItem

Comment: It is that you have implemented it in a wrong way, the position is the center of the rectangle in which the item is drawn, and you have not worked with them. Exactly what do you want to get in your project?

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear. I mean the value of getPos()  and getScenePos() of the QEdgeGraphicItem. I print those values on the output for the Nodes and the Edge on every repain to see any change. Node position are updated, edge podition don't.

Comment: This is not changing because you've never moved it.

Comment: I want to get the current position of the Edge. If its not updated any child item is draw at 0,0. As you said the position should be the center of the bounding rect, but getScenePos return 0,0. And I don't know how to get it right.

Comment: That you use the paint function does not imply that the figure has moved, but you have drawn it elsewhere.

Comment: The movement of the edge always depend on the node position. I got this from the QT Elastic Node example. Maybe I missed something. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: What I can do is create classes differently and print those data, would that be okay?

Comment: I know  that paint() only draw. The changes on the edge are computed on the adjust() method. It call prepareGeometryChange() that I guessed it should also update the position, but it don't.

Comment: Thank you but What I really need is the QEdgeGraphicItem label, that is set as a child item, to be drawn in the middle of the edge. But as you can see it's drawn on the middel of the scene. It's because the position of its father is 0,0.

Comment: Okay, so wait, please.

Comment: How do you want the text, aligned with the line?

Comment: It would be alwais horizontal.

Comment: @eyllanesc, any clue?